# C# How to lock calls to non-performant code

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I have a lock object in a class called **Loadeable**:

```
private readonly object _lock;
```

The `lock(_lock){ /*...*/ }` statements are only used inside the class **Loadable** to prevent deadlocks. *(Note: The accessor of the _lock object is private)*

Since I still wanted to run locked code from the outside I added the following method to the **Loadable** class:

```
public void RunLockedProcedure(Action Procedure) {
   lock(_lock) {
      Procedure();
   }
}
```

**Loadable** also contains a property called `IsLoaded` and a method called `Load(int)` but I do not show them because it is a lot of code and not really important. However it is important to note that `IsLoaded` and `Load(int)` access thread-safe data.

Now imagine **subclasses of Loadable called Item and Creation**. 
The integer `_creationId` and the following method are members of **Item**:

```
public Creation LazyGetCreation() {
   int creationIdCopy = 0;

   //The following lambda provides thread-safety inside this instance.
   RunLockedProcedure(() => {
      if(!IsLoaded) {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("A component cannot be loaded if the instance is not loaded");
      } else {
         if(_creationId < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The loaded Id of the creation component (" + _creationId + ") is less than 1.");

         creationIdCopy = _creationId;
         if(Creation == null)
            Creation = new Creation();
      }
   });

   //We are not in a thread-safe block and thus Creation might already be null again (I had to use the elvis operator)
   Creation?.RunLockedProcedure(() => {
      if(!Creation.IsLoaded)
         Creation.Load(creationIdCopy); //This is a heavy operation and takes a bit time...
   });
}
```

Let me eyplain the problem now:
The elvis operator is great, but the call to `Creation(?).RunLockedProcedure(() => { /*...*/ })` should really be performed inside the thread-safe block above (It requires the **Item** to be loaded). 
But then I get the problem that the very heavy `Creation.Load(creationIdCopy)` would also be performed in the locked block and thus lockes the **Item** for quite some time. What I am looking for is a way to safely call `Creation.RunLockedProcedure(/*...*/)` but to perform `() => { /*...*/ }` in a non-locked scope. (Must sill be locked to the Creation instance but not to the Item instance)

Maybe there is a feature I do not yet know, but it would be wounderful to find a solution. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The thread-safe guarantee should probably be handled in `Load` itself, not externally. Otherwise you need this in every place you call load. Something like this might work for you:

```
private object _lock = new object();
public void Load(int someID)
{
    if (IsLoaded) //No-locked check, early exit.
        return;

    lock (_lock) //We think it's not loaded, lock to prevent issues and double check
        if (IsLoaded)
            return;
        else
            IsLoaded = true; //Immediately set IsLoaded = true

    try 
    {
        //Do loading stuff
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        lock(_lock)
            IsLoaded = false; //We failed to load, set back to false again

        throw;
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
public Creation LazyGetCreation() {
   int creationIdCopy = 0;

   //The following lambda provides thread-safety inside this instance.
   RunLockedProcedure(() => {
      if(!IsLoaded) {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("A component cannot be loaded if the instance is not loaded");
      } else {
         if(_creationId < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The loaded Id of the creation component (" + _creationId + ") is less than 1.");

         creationIdCopy = _creationId;
         if(Creation == null)
            Creation = new Creation();
      }
   });

   Creation.Load(creationIdCopy);
}
```

If you don't like immediately setting `IsLoaded`, you could introduce `IsLoading` and check that both are false before creating the object, and immediately set `IsLoading` to true.

Comment: Interesting point. I will probably change some of my code, because you just mentioned something I really should do. However, you are still missing the point (Might be hard to understand from my explanation) Your call to Creation.Load(int) is not inside the RunLockedProcedure lambda and thus it is not guaranteed that Creation is not null. Maybe I can create a copy of the reference of Creation inside the locked lambda and then call load on that copy outside the lambda? (I want to call Load inside but execute it outside to keep the lock-time as short as possible)

Comment: It will be guaranteed to not be null, because `RunLockedProcedure` is locked and has three exit points: 2 throw exceptions, and the third has a guarantee that `Creation` is not null, since it creates it. Unless you have other code which explicitly sets `Creation` to null and runs in a separate thread (in which case we'd need to see the whole code/ rethink the design)

Comment: `Maybe I can create a copy of the reference of Creation inside the locked lambda and then call load on that copy outside the lambda?` - yes, that would work - however I would be hesitant because it's likely that if `Creation` is now null, the load no longer is required. Note that `Creation?.RunLockedProcedure` can still throw a null reference exception. We might need more information about what you're trying to accomplish to give a more thorough answer